# Is it possible for certain routes to use vue router while other routes use laravel router?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vue-router, laravel-routing

What I have is an existing laravel application with blades , laravel routes and a few vue components. So I don't want to replace the existing routes with vue router. What I want is to add additional routes without disturbing the existing laravel routes.

For an example I have a category which already is using the following category

```
Route::get('category/index' , 'CategoryController@index')->name('category.index');
```

Then I would like to add  a new route using vue router without disturbing the category route

For an example:

```
import Dashboard from "../views/Dashboard.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Dashboard",
    component: Dashboard,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  }
]
```

Is this possible?

Update: This is what I did (If anyone can point out what am I doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated)

1.0 Install Vue Router using npm

2.0 App.js (Use Vue Router)

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
    { path: '/dashboard', component:  require('./components/Dashboard')},
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes, // short for `routes: routes` 
    mode: 'history',
});
```

3.0 Web.php

```
Route::get('/{vue_capture?}', function () {
    return view('testing.main');
 })->where('vue_capture', '^(?!storage).*$');
```

4.0 main.blade.php(in testing folder)

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container" id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
@endsection
```

5.0 It doesn't work

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I believe this should be possible.

You will need to add a Laravel route that captures all the vue routes and shows a view which includes the vue routes.

```
Route::get('/vue/{vue_capture?}', function () {
   return view('vue.index');
})->where('vue_capture', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

You should be able to include both this route and the original Laravel ones.  One option would be to prefix the view routes as shown above with `/vue`, alternatively if you put the routes in the correct order you should be able to avoid the prefix, if you so wish.

The `php artisan route:list` command will help you, by allowing you to see what the current routes are.

Comment: So there is a laravel view which acts a master template which is index.blade.php which is in the vue folder. So in the index there is a <router-view></router-view> ?

Comment: Note that if you clear the route it will error `Unable to prepare route [vue/{vue_capture?}] for serialization. Uses Closure.`

Comment: @Aslam yes this is correct, you can use `Route::view('/vue/{vue_capture?}', 'vue.index')` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#view-routes to avoid this issue

Comment: @desh yes you would have one view as you describe, which would contain the `router-view` tag

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and simple.

All you need is to put the existing route at the top over the route that handles for vue app.

it should look like this.

**web.php**

```
// existing route
Route::get('category/index' , 'CategoryController@index')->name('category.index');

// handle vue app
Route::get('{path}', 'VueController')->where('path', '(.*)');
```

**VueController**

```
public function __invoke()
{
   reuturn view('index');
}
```

for working example you can read this section to work with vue-router [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html)