# addRoute doesn't update route list

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I try to adding routes to my router while the application is already running, more specifically after the connection.

I have this in my app.js

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [

    {
        path : '/',
        name: 'principal',
        component : PrincipalComponent,
    },
    {
        path : '/403',
        component : Erreur403Component,
    }
];

const router = new VueRouter({routes});

export {router}
```

And in my vuex

```
import {router} from "../app.js"

const actions = {

     loginUser({state, commit}, user) {

           return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

               axios.get('/menuGeneration')
                    .then(data => {
                        data.data.forEach(route => {
                             router.addRoute({
                                path : "\test"
                             });
                             router.push("\test");
                        })
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(error);

               console.log(router.getRoutes());
           })
      }
}
```

But I only have the first 2 routes declared in app.js

[image: Text]

I have checked that axios sends me the list of menus

If anyone has a lead, I'm intereste !

For information :
vue@2.6.12
vue-router@3.6.5
vuex@3.6.0

**UPDATE**

After the advice yoduh of I modified the code following

```
axios.get('/menuGeneration')
                    .then(data => {
                        data.data.forEach(route => {
                             router.addRoute({
                                path : "/test",
                                component : TestComponent
                             });                        
                        })
                        console.log(router.getRoutes());
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(error);
```

And it's work

[image: Text]

But when i add a replaces for the current resource

```
axios.get('/menuGeneration')
                    .then(data => {
                        data.data.forEach(route => {
                             router.addRoute({
                                path : "/test",
                                component : TestComponent
                             });                        
                        })
                        window.location.replace('/dashboard')
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(error);
```

it does not guard the routes.

what is the way to keep the routes ?

Comment: first, routes need forward slashes, e.g. `/test`.  second, you've only defined the path, not what component should be rendered by that path.  without that information it only knows what the URL should be but not what that URL should load.  import a component and add it to the route object.  `{path: '/test', component: myComponent}`

Comment: OK ! Now, i see my route in "console.log(router.getRoutes());", but in vue devtools plugin, there are only the first 3.

Comment: sometimes the dev tools need a manual refresh to show the most up to date information.  i'm not sure if this is the case here, but a better test to know for sure would be: does the `/test` route load?  otherwise, please update the code snippet in your question to show what exactly you've changed and include any new errors you might be getting from your console

Comment: i update the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

> it does not guard the routes.
>
> what is the way to keep the routes ?

You must always navigate using vue-router if you want vue-router's navigation guards to activate on route changes.  This line:

```js
window.location.replace('/dashboard')
```

can be replaced with the vue-router [replace](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#replace-current-location) equivalent which will activate your navigation guards

```js
router.replace('/dashboard')
```

Comment: "dashboard" is a another blade file. how i suppose to indicated in vue router ?

Comment: ah, you didn't mention you were working with blade files before, and unfortunately I'm not familiar with laravel.  maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64841952) can help you